# Try/Catch block in script not working

Tags: powershell, scripting

The premise of the script below is that I need it to look through a folder of PDFs which will be named after the individual they are for, this will then match the name to an email in an accompanying CSV file and generate an email which sends the appropriate PDFs to them.

The problem is we have a send/receive limit of 10MB, so I've been trying to figure out a `try/catch` block which will email someone if some PDFs fail to send, but in it's current state it seems to stop the script if it encounters an error and doesn't send messages to anyone else.

Can someone provide some suggestions on maybe how to get this working, or any better solutions?

I have been looking at `do/while` to see if I can get it to loop until the attachments being sent are equal to 10MB and then send that message and restart but can't figure it out.

Any assistance is GREATLY appreciated, and let me know if anything is wrong/you need more info.

```
$CSV = Import-Csv "\\Server\Share\NamesAndEmails.csv"
$PDFFolder = "\\Server\Share\PDF Folder"

$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"

ForEach($User in $CSV)
{
    $PDFs = Get-ChildItem -Path $PDFFolder | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".pdf" -and $_.Name -like "*$($User.Name)*" }

    $to = $User.Email
    $from = "email@domain.com"
    $smtp = "smtp.domain.com"
    $body = "Please see attachments."
    $attachments = @()

    ForEach($PDF in $PDFs)
    {
        $attachments += $PDF.FullName
    }

    $MessageParameters = @{
        From = $from
        To = $to
        Subject = "Email subject"
        Body = $body
        SmtpServer = $smtp
        Attachments = $attachments
    } 

    try 
    { 
        Send-MailMessage @MessageParameters 
    } 
    Catch 
    {            
        Send-MailMessage `
            -smtp smtp.domain.com `
            -to "Name <email@domain.com>" `
            -from "Name <email@domain.com>" `
            -subject "Failed to send post for $($user.Name)" `
            -body "Please go to \\... and resend PDF's for $($user.name) across multiple messages as necessary." `
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting the `-ErrorAction Stop` switch on your `Send-MailMessage @MessageParameters` line. See the answers/links on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792722/powershell-logging-errors/30793204  for more info.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx (scroll down to section on Try/Catch/Finally Blocks)

Comment: Tried that, still the same I'm afraid.
As an example, currently I have 2 names in the CSV and 2 docs named after them, one is 11MB (which it too large) the other only a few KB. Currently the script runs, sends a warning to the specified account saying "The attachment for user1 is too large", but then ceases and doesn't send the other file to user2- this is what I need to get around.

I'll take a look at those links as well, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Can you post a sample CSV file that repro's this problem. I'm thinking it's something shonky with that or how it's being handled

Comment: Are you sure catch block does not throw anything itself?
Also try using $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

Comment: @Kev Just out the office at the moment so don't have access to the file but it's basically:  
Name,Email  
User1,User1@domain.com  
User2,User2@domain.com

Comment: @YpsilonIV If I remove the catch the error is basically 'Maximum storage exceeded'- this seems to be a terminating error. Even if I mark the error action as Continue/SilentlyContinue the script will run and send all items that are <10MB but won't send any warnings that the files >10MB haven't sent.  If I set it to 'Stop', it'll send the warning but then nothing else.

Comment: I am thinking Send-MailMesage in catch block might have a problem itself. You can try wrapping in try-catch block within catch block.